# How to map a property that's a list of the same type

Tags: c#, automapper

This is the original type

```
public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? Level { get; set; }

    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> ChildrenCategory { get; } = new List<Category>();
    public IList<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

I'm trying to map to this type

```
public class CategoryDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryDto> ChildreenCategory { get; } 
        = new List<CategoryDto>();
}
```

**Category** has a property called **ChildrenCategory** of type **List**.

I've tried this,

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>()
       .ForMember(d => d.ChildreenCategory,
                  o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ChildrenCategory));
                            ;
});
```

I'm getting an empty array when I run Postman

```
{
    "id": "c1a16772-31d1-4025-a1b9-7206066ffd94",
    "categoryName": "Women",
    "parentCategoryId": null,
    "childreenCategory": []
},
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try using "ResolveUsing" instead of "MapFrom". I remember there was an issue with MapFrom when mapping recursive objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your destination DTO property `ChildreenCategory` has no setter, so it will always be set to the empty list. Adding the setter allows your child objects to be mapped:

```
public List<CategoryDto> ChildreenCategory { get; set; }
```

If you make the spelling of `ChildreenCategory` on your DTO to match the source class, then you can remove the whole `ForMember` call on your mapping definition, as it will be wired up automatically.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>();            
});
```

Comment: It can work without a setter. It just needs UseDestinationValue.

Comment: @john McDowall, it's working. I fix the misspelling on the dto class.

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#usedestinationvalue

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, +1